Mixed configuration of magneto-optical kerr effect
Typically there are three types of magneto-optical Kerr effect experiments: Polar, longitudinal, and transverse. These three geometries yield very different results regarding what is measured (polarization rotation or intensity change). These three configurations have very well-defined dielectric tensors, and interpreting data is rather simple.
I have a situation where I need to mount my sample in the longitudinal configuration. However, the sample's magnetic easy axis is in the z direction (let's say the sample interface is the xy-plane, and the external B field is in the x-direction). I build a polarimeter that shines laser light onto the sample with the plane of incidence being the xz-plane (just like a typical longitudinal MOKE experiment would), and I want to measure the change in signal as I vary the applied B field and temperature of the sample. Ideally, you would not use this configuration and would opt for the typical polar moke experiment. Still, I am stuck with this "mixed configuration" between longitudinal B-field and polar magnetic sample for reasons that aren't relevant here. As for the sample, the z-axis is ferromagnetic, while the xy-axes are paramagnetic. I should also note that the material is not a thin film but a single crystal.
I cannot find any instance of a polarimeter used this way in the literature (with M in the z-direction, B in the x direction, and the plane of incidence in the xz plane). I certainly do not know how to calculate the corresponding dielectric tensor for this geometry. This is very important for my experiment because I cannot design the apparatus without understanding the nature of the signal change as the B-field is swept. It could be that I have to measure an intensity change rather than a polarization change. Or a mixture of the two? I have no idea, and it seems there is very little out there regarding non-ideal MOKE geometries and how to interpret them.
Any help or ideas would be hugely appreciated. I have been scouring the literature for something like this, and it has been surprising how little there seems to be. It seems physicists tend to pick samples that work with well-known and ideal configurations and avoid situations like the one I am currently in.
Thank you.
